# A simple prolog program

Tags: prolog

I want to implement the following function `f(x,y)` in Prolog

```
f(x,y) = a*x+b*y
where a = 1 if x > 0; a = -1 if x < 0; a = 0 if x = 0
and b = -1 if y > 0; b = 1 if y < 0; b = 0 if y = 0
```

For example,

```
f(2,-1) = 1*2 + 1*(-1) = 1
f(-2,-1) = (-1)*(-2) + (-1)*1 = 1
f(0,0) = 0*0 + 0*0 = 0
```

Any one can help?

Comment: Prolog don't work exactly that way. Prolog is not functional, Prolog is logic. so You have to define proposition that are true. Then you can ask question to Prolog and he will try to give an answer (yes or no) and the variable substitution if the reponse is yes.

Comment: But you can't arrive on SO and simply asking for "Learn me that language". SO is here to help you when you are stuck with a peace of code that you are working on.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin: I dont think so, in fact we can still have such a function in Prolog, an example is the problem to add two numbers. Prolog infers facts based on facts and rules in its database, not just simply answers yes-no questions.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin: You can see several Prolog examples here http://www.anselm.edu/homepage/mmalita/culpro/index.html. You can reserve a list in Prolog, not just query yes-no questions, right?

Comment: Yes it's what I mean by "variable substitutions" :-) I'm not very clear in my comment. But it don't change the fact that he have to search a litle, try something and then come back if he don't find the solution by himself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you have a typo when defining y, y>0 not y>=0.)
You need to define a relation between the input vars and the result of the function. Prolog can then answer yes/true with substitutions or no/false.

```
f(X,Y,Answer):-
    a_is(X,A),
    b_is(Y,B),
    Answer is A*X+B*Y.

a_is(X,1):-
    X>0.
a_is(X,-1):-
    X<0.
a_is(0,0).

b_is(Y,1):-
    Y<0.
b_is(Y,-1):-
    Y>0.
b_is(0,0).
```

Example:

```
?-f(2,-1,Answer).
Answer =1;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following formulation?

```
f(X,Y,Result) :-
   Result is abs(X) - abs(Y).
```

Let's run some queries:

```
?- f(0,0,0).
true.

?- f(-2,-1,1).
true.

?- f(2,-1,1).
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be much more complicated than this one-liner:

```
f(X,Y,Z) :- Z is sign(X)*X + -sign(Y)*Y
```